# Entity Proxy Change Listener in GWT Request Factory

Tags: gwt, data-binding, requestfactory

I wish to achieve birectional binding of UI and data using Request Factory Proxies, and for that part I need a way to listen to the changes in a EntityProxy or a ValueProxy. If they were ordinary models, I could have attached my view to the model's change listener, but in request factory, the models or "proxies" are interfaces and I can't figure out, how to let the view know when a "setter" method is called.

Is there a way I can do this, without wrapping the proxy and delegating the setters to proxy, while at the same time raise events ? I want the functionality to be "plugged in" directly into the proxy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have actually come up with a workaround. We tapped into the GWT generator code and added a `Listener` field in the autobean proxy. After that we appended a `listener.execute()` in each of the generated `setter` methods. So now we can attach `change listeners` to the proxy and listen to them.

The only thing that worries me, is a `JSNI` call used to call a protected method and also tapping into the GWT generator code. How fine is this?

Answer (score 0):

I also thought and researched abit on the matter, but haven't gotten around to it yet.

I think you need to take a look at the gwt MobileWebApp example.
They have a Task domain object, it has a proxy interface, but they **use an implementation of the interface on the client side** instead (see TaskProxy & TaskProxyImpl)

I would love to hear if you'll make some progress with this.
Hope this helps

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer, can you take a look at the approach I have posted below. It seems to work, but is it fine?